# Function in R that performs multiple operations over columns of two datasets

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have two datasets, each with 5 columns and 10,000 rows. I want to calculate `y` from values in columns between the two datasets, column 1 in data set 1 and column 1 in data set 2; then column 2 in data set 1 and column 2 in data set 2. The `y`needs nonetheless to follow a set of rules before being calculated. What I did so far doesn't work, and I cannot figure it out why and if there is a easier way to do all of this.

1. Create data from t-distributions

```
mx20 <- as.data.frame(replicate(10000, rt(20,19)))
mx20.50 <- as.data.frame(replicate(10000, rt(20,19)+0.5))
```

2. Calculates the mean for each simulated sample

```
m20 <- apply(mx20, FUN=mean, MARGIN=2)
m20.05 <- apply(mx20.50, FUN=mean, MARGIN=2)
```

The steps **1 and 2**_ above are repeated for five sample sizes from t-distributions `rt(30,29); rt(50,49); rt(100,99); and rt(1000,999)`

3. Bind tables (create data.frame) for each t-distribution specification

```
tbl <- cbind(m20, m30, m50, m100, m1000)
tbl.50 <- cbind(m20.05, m30.05, m50.05, m100.05, m1000.05)
```

4. Finally, I want to calculate the y as specified above. But here is where I get totally lost. Please see below my best attempt so far.

`y = (mtheo-m0)/(m1-m0)`, where y = 0 when m1 < m0 and y = y when m1 >= m0. mtheo is a constant (e.g. 0.50), m1 is value in column 1 of **tbl** and m0 is value in column 1 of **tbl.50**.

```
ycalc <- function(mtheo, m1, m0) {
  ifelse(m1>=m0) {
    y = (mteo-m0)/(m1-m0)
  } ifelse(m1<m0) {
    y=0
  } returnValue(y)
}
```

Comment: Note that your lines in step 1 do not create t realizations.  The first parameter is the number of realizations.  I.e. `mx20 <- as.data.frame(rt(10000,20,19))`

Comment: @SteveM I was hoping that line gives me values from a t-distribution with ```m=0```, ```sd=1``` taken from a sample with ```n=20```. The ```replicate``` function because i want 10,000 samples drawn from the specified t-distribution. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. I used data frames instead of data tables.

This code is more versatile. You can add or remove parameters. Below are the parameters that you can use to create t distributions.

```
params = data.frame(
    n = c(20, 30, 50, 100, 1000),
    df = c(19, 29, 49, 99, 999)
    )
```

And here is a loop that creates the values you need for each t distribution. You can ignore this part if you already have those values (or code to create those values).

```
tbl = data.frame(i = c(1:10000))
tbl.50 = data.frame(i = c(1:10000))
for (i in 1:nrow(params)) {
    mx = as.data.frame(replicate(10000, rt(params[i, 1], params[i, 2])))
    m <- apply(mx, FUN=mean, MARGIN=2)
    tbl = cbind(tbl, m)
    names(tbl)[ncol(tbl)] = paste("m", params[i, 1], sep="")
    mx.50 = as.data.frame(replicate(10000, rt(params[i, 1], params[i, 2])+.5))
    m.50 <- apply(mx.50, FUN=mean, MARGIN=2)
    tbl.50 = cbind(tbl.50, m.50)
    names(tbl.50)[ncol(tbl.50)] = paste("m", params[i, 1], ".50", sep="")
}
tbl = tbl[-1]
tbl.50 = tbl.50[-1]
```

And here is the loop that does the calculations. I save them in a data frame (y). Each column in this data frame is the result of your function applied for all rows.

```
mtheo = .50
y = data.frame(i = c(1:10000))
for (i in 1:nrow(params)) {
    y$dum = 0
    idx = which(tbl[, i] >= tbl.50[, i])
    y[idx, ]$dum = 
                    (mtheo - tbl.50[idx, i]) / 
                    (tbl[idx, i] - tbl.50[idx, i])
    names(y)[ncol(y)] = paste("y", params[i, 1], sep="")
}
y = y[-1]
```

Comment: thank you so much! This is spot on exactly what I've been trying to get at the past 2 weeks. Your answer is elegant, easy to follow, and give me what I need. Perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, if the first column in `tbl` is called `m0` and the first column in `tbl.50` is called `m1`:

```
mteo <- 0.5
ycalc <- ifelse(tbl$m1 >= tbl.50$m0, (mteo - tbl.50$m0)/(tbl$m1 - tbl.50$m0),
                ifelse(tbl$m1 < tbl.50$m0), 0, "no")
```

Using the same column names provided by your code, and transforming your matrices into dataframes:

```
tbl <- data.frame(tbl)
tbl.50 <- data.frame(tbl.50)
mteo <- 0.5
ycalc <- ifelse(tbl$m20 >= tbl.50$m20.05, (mteo - tbl.50$m20.05)/(tbl$m20 - tbl.50$m20.05),
                ifelse(tbl$m20 < tbl.50$m20.05, "0", "no"))
```

This results in:

```
head(ycalc)
[1] "9.22491706576716" "0"                "0"                "0"                "0"                "1.77027049630147"
```

Comment: Thank you @bttomio! Will this iterate also over 5 columns in across two data frames? I hear that a function is best to avoid applying ifelse multiple times by hand.

Comment: You're welcome, hope it helps you out. I edited my answer. It will only execute the date considering the specified columns (```m0``` and ```m1```).

Comment: your answer is also working very well. Thank you! Though, I find the answer by HaciDuru to be exactly what I was trying to get at, so I will accept his/her.